# How to shipping charges in magento invoice page?

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, php-5.4

I have a invoice and I want to show shipping charges of particular product on that invoice please tell me which code I have to add. below is the code.`

```
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Product Details</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <?php   
                $items = $this->getorderitems();
                $total = 0;
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                 $product = $this->loadproduct($item->getProductId());
                 ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
<?php echo $item->getName(); ?><br>
                    SKU : <?php echo $item->getSku(); ?><br>Order No.: #
                <?php if ($this->getNoUseOrderLink()): ?>
                    <?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId(); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId(); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
</td>
                    <td><?php echo round($item->getQtyOrdered()); ?></td>
                    <td><?php 
                    echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($item->getBaseRowTotalInclTax(), true, false); 
                    $amount = $item->getBaseRowTotalInclTax();
                     $total = $total + $amount;
                      ?></td>
                  </tr>


                <?php }

                 ?>

                   <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td><strong>Total : </strong></td>
                  <td>
                  <strong>
                  <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($total, true, false) ?></td>
                  </strong>
                  </tr>

                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
`
```

Comment: hello reply anyone

Comment: Are you able to see what results are in `$_order` ? This should have the shipping amount charged.

Comment: there is no option for showing shipping charges

Answer (score 0):

Within the `$_order` object you can access the shipping amount charged for the order by `$_order->getShippingAmount()`;

You should also be able to get the Shipping carrier by calling `$_order->getShippingCarrier` If you look at `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` this will give you all the available methods for the order.

Comment: i have product shipping charges  per product and i want to show per peroduct shipping charges and that shipping chrges i want to show in total amount

Comment: How do the per product shipping amounts get charged? Are they implemented via a shipping carrier?

Comment: i am using a extension and it has a attribute product_shipping. when i add a new product then i fill that column a shipping charge. this charge i want to show not all products shipping charges.

Comment: also after adding code shipping charge code its showing 29.0000 after decimal its showing four zero i want to show 2 or no zero